# ParametricNDSolveValue has a problem with complex numbers

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, parametric-functions

**Bug introduced in version 10 and fixed in 10.3**

**Edited:** I have simplified the example compared to before and narrowed the problem down a bit.

I would like to use `ParametricNDSolveValue` as function for data fitting. However, I am having trouble with one parameter. That is, `ParametricNDSolveValue` evaluates just fine when I fix the parameter upfront, but not when I only assign a value to the parameter in the evaluated function.

### Preparations

```
R[t_] = Through[#[t]] & /@ Table[Subscript[r, i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
```

### Problem

I now try to compute the `ParametricNDSolveValue` with `n` being a parameter.

```
ParametricNDSolveValue[{R'[t]==I R[t], R[0]==DiagonalMatrix[{0, n}]}, Subscript[r,2,2], {t,0,10}, {n}][1][1]
```

> 0.0 + 0.0 I

So that has not worked. But when I fix `n` in the DE the result is different.

```
ParametricNDSolveValue[{R'[t]==I R[t], R[0]==DiagonalMatrix[{0, 1}]}, Subscript[r,2,2], {t,0,10}, {n}][1][1]
```

> 0.540302 + 0.841471 I

Alternatively, when I remove the `I` in the DE, I get a nontrivial result even with `n` in the DE.

```
ParametricNDSolveValue[{R'[t]==  R[t], R[0]==DiagonalMatrix[{0, n}]}, Subscript[r,2,2], {t,0,10}, {n}][1][1]
```

> 2.71828

### Question

Does anybody understand what is going on? Does `ParametricNDSolveValue` have a problem with complex numbers and matrices (it does not if the DE are only scalars)?

Thanks a lot for any input!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this was a bug. It's fixed in Version 10.3.

Comment: You may want to add a [bugs header](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1611/18476).

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug introduced in v10. As of v9, these are the results:

```
R[t_] = Through[#[t]] & /@ Table[Subscript[r, i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
ParametricNDSolveValue[{R'[t] == I R[t], R[0] == DiagonalMatrix[{0, n}]}, 
   Subscript[r, 2, 2], {t, 0, 10}, {n}][1][1]
ParametricNDSolveValue[{R'[t] == I R[t], R[0] == DiagonalMatrix[{0, 1}]}, 
   Subscript[r, 2, 2], {t, 0, 10}, {n}][1][1]

(* 0.540302 + 0.841471 I *)
(* 0.540302 + 0.841471 I *)
```